# Multiply values from excel fields with if conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is my excel example, i need to get values in column NEW COST

[image: My excel example]

1. If string in product name contains () and in that brackets are words like: pck,pcs,pack or pots, new cost will be the same value like cost
2. If dont and the quantity is bigger then 0, new cost will be Cost*Quantity. If this condition is true, it should create new column that will write This is new cost.
3. If Quantity is 0 then new cost is the same like cost.

Can someone help me to create formula for this?

Comment: What did you try out already and what errors/unwanted results are you getting? We are not free coders/formula writers on this platform so it would be good to show the effort you put in already. 
Seems this should be straight forward enough for usage of some IF statementes

Comment: Yes i tried a lot of options:

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pack",A2)) - this i what if found for searching word in string, but i dont know how i can add here, more words then one, also how to write else condition after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that "Product name" is in A1, you can paste this formula into D2:

```
    =IF(AND(IF(IFERROR(FIND("(";A2;1);0)=0;0;1);OR(IF(IFERROR(FIND("pack";A2;1);0)=0;0;1);
IF(IFERROR(FIND("pck";A2;1);0)=0;0;1);IF(IFERROR(FIND("pcs";A2;1);0)=0;0;1);
IF(IFERROR(FIND("pots";A2;1);0)=0;0;1)));C2;C2*B2)
```

If "This is new cost" could be in column E, then paste this into E2:

```
=IF(C2=D2;"This is new cost")
```

Comment: Do you have English Excel? It works for me fine: https://prnt.sc/l7vdfk

Comment: I just copied the formula straight out of my excel, please try again (I modified the code in my answer above)

Comment: maybe your excel uses , instead of ; in the formulas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Evaluation()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim Result As Integer

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
        If (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, "(") > 0) And (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, ")") > 0) Then
            If (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, "pck") > 0) Or (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, "pcs") > 0) Or (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, "pack") > 0) Or (InStr(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value, "pots") > 0) Then
                Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value
            End If
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value * Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```